# Can Xcode-beta identified as normal Xcode?

Tags: xcode, meteor, xcode7

I want to test the [Meteor iOS build feature](https://www.meteor.com/try/7) with Xcode 7 Beta. Only the Xcode Beta version is installed on my machine, and the given Meteor terminal command says 'Xcode is not installed'. It is probably because the Beta is actually called 'xcode-beta'. Are there any ways, to solve this?

The command I stuck with:

```
meteor install-sdk ios
```

Comment: Temporarily rename the app to Xcode.

Comment: Yep, this solved it. Trivial solution. Thanks!